# There is no active transaction

Tags: mysql, laravel, stored-procedures, transactions

I want to call a stored procedure which creates a dynamic view within a transaction in Laravel:

Laravel:

```php
try {
    DB::transaction(function() use ($raison_sociale_clean, $coming) {          
        DB::statement('CALL ps_creer_view_des_produits_fournisseur_supp(?,?)',[substr($raison_sociale_clean,0,30),$coming->id]);
        
        DB::table('produits')->where('fournisseurs_id','=',$coming->id)->delete();
        DB::table('fournisseurs')->whereid($coming->id)->delete();
    });
    
    echo 'Transaction passée sans erreurs';
} catch(QueryException $e) {
    echo "Error dans la requête: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

MySQL:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE IF NOT EXISTS ps_creer_view_des_produits_fournisseur_supp(IN nom_view varchar(30), IN id_fournisseur int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE query varchar(1000);
    set query = concat('CREATE VIEW supp_fournisseur_', nom_view, '_prod AS
    SELECT p.id as produit_id, p.designation, p.prix, p.date_expiration, f.id as fournisseurs_id, f.raison_sociale, f.adresse, f.tele
    FROM produits p
    INNER JOIN fournisseurs f
    ON p.fournisseurs_id=f.id
    WHERE fournisseurs_id=', id_fournisseur);
    PREPARE view_supp from query;
    EXECUTE view_supp;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE view_supp;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

When I remove the statement that contains the stored procedure, the transaction goes well, so the problem resides in it. It's important to note that the view is created successfully with the given fournisseur and product records deleted. Still, the error message "there is no active transaction" always pops up.

I searched and found that the problem may be in the autocommit, like if the stored procedure makes a commit itself, so when the transaction tries to make its commit or rollback, it will be treated as a new commit of an unknown transaction.

Comment: Why do you have such a complex code/query instead of using Eloquent? Do not mix MySQL Transactions with code, you are adding logic into a database, and it is unmaintainable using Laravel, requires a very good team, just my recommendation, just eloquent, and normal queries/models

Comment: it's true , i just was trying to discover query builder before going to Eloquent

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not support DDL (create view, for instance) inside a transaction.  The create view will [implicitly commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html) the transaction, and the next DML statement will be a new transaction.  Do your create view before your transaction.

Looking at it more closely, your immediate problem (DDL ending the transaction) isn't the only problem.  You are creating a view, but then deleting the produits that view would find?  That will leave you with an empty view. If you are trying to save the rows that you are deleting, this is not how you do it; MySQL does not support materialized views.  You will need to create a table and copy the data into it before deleting.

Comment: now i get it thanks !